# How come the gevent spawn is not working as I think it would?

Tags: python, gevent

When I telnet into the server and type something I expect the output to print 'after spawn' then print 'after sleep', but it does the reverse. Why is it that way? And how would I fix it to do that?

```
import sys, signal
from gevent.server import StreamServer
from gevent.pool import Pool
from gevent import monkey
import gevent

def signal_handler(signal, frame): sys.exit(0)

class SocketPool(object):

    def __init__(self): self.pool = Pool(1000)

    def listen(self, socket):
        while True:
            line = socket.recv(1024)
            if not line:
                socket.close()
                break
            gevent.spawn(self.wait).join()
            print 'after spawn'

    def add_handler(self, socket, address):
        if self.pool.full(): raise Exception("At maximum pool size")
        else: self.pool.spawn(self.listen, socket)

    def wait(self):
        gevent.sleep(7)
        print 'after sleep'

    def shutdown(self): self.pool.kill()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
monkey.patch_all()
sockPool = SocketPool()
server = StreamServer(('127.0.0.1', 5000), sockPool.add_handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `join` call after spawning the greenlet. With `join` you are waiting till this greenlet is finished.